# ionic app doesn't switch between pages

Tags: ionic-framework

I am only asking for someone to please look at my code and tell me why I can't go from login to sign up page after clicking a button.

my login page code is

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" >
<ion-content class="padding">
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="email">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
    </label>
    <button class="button">login</button>
     <a  nav-transition="android" href="#/sign-up">
        <button class="button">Sign up</button>
    </a>
    <button class="button">Forgot password</button>
</ion-content>
```

my sign up page looks like this

```
<ion-view view-title="Sign Up" >
```

```
<!-- content goes here -->
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <h2>My Profile</h2>
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Age*</span>
            <input type="range" name="volume" min="18" max="100" value="21">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Gender*</span>
            <select>
                <option>Male</option>
                <option>Female</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

finally my app.js page looks like

```
 // angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('social-arena', ['ionic', 'social-arena.controllers', 'social-arena.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
      // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
      // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
      // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
      $stateProvider

      // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
          'login': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
          }
        }
      })

      .state('signup', {
          url: '/signup',
          views: {
            'signup': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/sign-up.html',
              controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
            }
          }
        });


      // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your href to look like this:

```
<a  nav-transition="android" href="#/signup">
```

the href should match the url you give in your state:

```
.state('signup', {
      url: '/signup', // should match this
      views: {
        'signup': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/sign-up.html', //not this
          controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
        }
      }
    });
```

not the template url.

**edit**

I see in the comments in your code that you are trying to use the tabs directive and I also noticed that you are missing an abstract state, [Ionic's](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-2/) guide for setting up routing can help you through the steps.

**From the example on Ionic Docs**

```
$stateProvider.state('app.todos', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/todos',
  views: {
    todos: {
      template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>'
    }
  }
})
```

As you can see, they set one view as and abstract

```
abstract:true,
```

and then have the rest of your views link to the abstract, again from the docs:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.todos.index', {
  url: '',
  templateUrl: 'todos.html',
  controller: 'TodosCtrl'
})
```

Comment: so when I copied what you said directly, button was still unresponsive. file name is sign-up.html and when I changed href to `<a  nav-transition="android" href="/sign-up">` and state to             `.state('signup', {
      url: '/sign-up', // should match this
      views: {
        'signup': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/sign-up.html', //not this
          controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
        }
      }
    });` my site did change pages but I got a message "Cannot GET /sign-up "

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer and found a guide from the Ionic Docs. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ui-sref` to go to a state:

```
<a nav-transition="android" ui-sref="signup">
```

Or href to go to a url:

```
<a nav-transition="android" href="#/signup">
```